# XSL how to select every tab that begins with a certain set of characers?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to create an xsl file that will go through an xml file and only process tags that begin with a certain set of characters. I should mention that I am fairly new to xsl files and so this may be really easy to accomplish but I just don't know how.

My xml file looks similar to this:

```
<generic_etd>
   <associated_tags>
      <master>
         <dc.contributor>contributor</dc.contributor>
      </master>
      <related>
         <dc.contributor.role>contributor role</dc.contributor.role>
      </related> 
   </associated_tags>
   <associated_tags>
      <master>
         <dc.contributor>sponsor</dc.contributor>
      </master>
      <related>
         <dc.contributor.role>sponsor role</dc.contributor.role>
      </related>
   </associated_tags>
   <dc.creator>gradstudent2</dc.creator>
   <dc.date>2014-02-11</dc.date>
   <dc.description>description</dc.description>
   <thesis.degree.discipline>Business Administration</thesis.degree.discipline>
<generic_etd>
```

I want my xsl file to only process tags that begin with 'dc.'

This is the xsl file that I have come up with so far:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:choose>
        <!-- Process the tags we are interested in -->
        <xsl:when test="contains(name(),'dc.')">
            <xsl:variable name="newtag" select="concat('dc:',substring-after(name(),'.'))"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains($newtag, '.')">
                    <xsl:element name="{substring-before($newtag,'.')}">
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:element name="{$newtag}">
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

However the file it produces is missing dc.contributor and dc.contributor.role from the output. Actually, I would like to exclude dc.contributor.role in this example but I would need it in another file I am processing.

My question is where did I go wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Uhm.... Are you trying to move the dc.* elements into a namespace? If so, you'll want to assert that too on your replacement xsl:element. If not, you can't use a colon in an element name; that's reserved for use as a namespace prefix.

Comment: Yes I am namespacing it. I only showed the part of the code that I was having problems with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example stylesheet. It directly matches elements that start with `dc`

```
<xsl:stylesheet  version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:dc="http://www.example.com">
    <xsl:output method='xml' indent='yes'/>


    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:namespace name="dc">http://www.example.com</xsl:namespace>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(),'dc.')]">
        <xsl:variable name="newtag" select="concat('dc:',substring-after(name(),'.'))"/>
        <xsl:element name="{$newtag}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Well that is a much cleaner implementation then what I came up with. Thanks for the example.

Comment: You might want to check whether the name starts with "dc." rather than whether it contains it, just to make it a bit more robust... but outside of that, this should indeed work.

Comment: @keshlam, if you read the second sentence, I am going with starts-with. Maybe I forgot to change it when I copied the OP's code. :)

Comment: `<xsl:template match="*[contains(name(),'dc.')]">` is the line I'm grumbling about, and that's copied direct from what I'm seeing above. You might want to fix it.

Comment: Yeah, I did not fix it in the first instance for you to see my point first. Now I am going to change it.